# To prove or disprove, $d(p,X\setminus B_1)=d(p,B_2\setminus B_1)$, where $B_1\subset B_2$

Tags: metric-spaces

In a metric space $(X,d)$, if $B_1=B(x,r_1), B_2=B(x,r_2)$ are two open balls with $r_1<r_2$, and $p\in B_1$, then how to prove or disprove, $$d(p,X\setminus B_1)=d(p,B_2\setminus B_1)?$$

Here, for $A\subset X,$

$$d(x,A):=\inf_{a\in A}d(x,a) .$$

Comment: What have you tried? Do you think it's true or not true? Hint: draw a picture.

Comment: Hint: $\{d(x, y): y\in B_2-B_1\}\subseteq\{d(x, y): y\in X-B_1\}$ and for every $y\in X-B_2$,  $d(x, y)>r_{2}>d(x, B_2-B_1)$.